# Why is there no code completion when using "extern alias" in VS2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Here is code snippet:

```
extern alias customerRead;  
extern alias customerEdit;  
extern alias customerSearch;

using readC = customerRead::X.Y.DataAccess;  
using editC = customerEdit::X.Y.DataAccess;  
using searchC = customerSearch::X.Y.DataAccess;  
...  

readC.Customer c = new readC.Customer();  
c. // NO CODE COMPLETITION
```

I have aliases for all three projects in .project file and compiling from the IDE goes well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembly containing the aliased namespace is specified on the compiler command line as opposed to in a source document. I assume the issues here are:

- The binding of assemblies to the alias is indirect
- The IntelliSense name resolver doesn't check for names in aliased namespaces
- So few people use this feature that it's low priority on the "TODO" list